# Parse video source based on Flash Player

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to parse web page and get the url of video from src. Using browser the video tag inside the div looks like this one

```
<video style="width: 854px; height: 480px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/69bf4dd1-062f-487f-8ca7-6a2493f8dfc8"></video>
```

But when I use Jsoup it show me this message instead of video tag

```
You are seeing this message either because your Flash Player is outdated or because your browser does not support HTML5 player
```

This is my code:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(this.url)
                                      .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                                      .get();
```

How to get video src avoiding Flash Player support?

Comment: This might be to the lack of User Agent in your header. This parameter allows server you are trying to connect to recognize what kind of a client tries to connect and customize content. Try adding valid User Agent header, for example the one copied from request send via browser. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: I add User-Gent header, it still doesn't work

Comment: Then try if it is generated via javascript. Disable javascript in your browser and reload page. See what happens.